# Magento 2 local development incredibly slow, on powerful mac

Tags: magento2, development, magento2.3.5, speedoptimization, slow-response

When I say slow, I'm talking about over 3 minutes to load the customer signup page, which doesn't even do a db call!

I have a 2015 imac with 32gb ram, and a 50% empty ssd.

I'm not using any VM, just apache installed with Homebrew, and php 7.2, with 8092M of memory allocated. I updated the memory in both php.ini and .htacess file.

I have all caches enables, css/js minification turned off.

I disabled the browser cache, because I'm doing js work this week.

I'm getting almost nothing done here, because of how slowly requests come through.

Any ideas? I figured that not using a VM would be better, right?

Comment: FYI I develop on my MacBook Pro using an external SSD with Ubuntu in a 4GB VMWare Fusion VM and Magento 2 is very fast.

Comment: How is it possible that using a VM can be faster than a local apache/php/sql setup?